# Is this sentence correct or not?

Tags: expressions

This is a question for a questionnaire.  " what english skill do you need most?"; speaking or writing? I want to ask about the most used skill of English by the learners. 
Is this sentence correct or not?

Comment: Please remember that questions, that are just proof-reading requests are considered off-topic here. If you stumble about a *specific* question while writing or translating a text, we are glad to help.

Comment: [Lang-8](http://lang-8.com/) is a great site specifically for proofreading.

Comment: No my question is not about proofreading. It is about writing. I am writing a questionnaire and need help.

Comment: But maybe i haven't understood. Any way , thnk you so much for the Lang-8. I liked it.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is almost correct. I would add the word "the" and change the semi-colon to a colon. Also, English should be capitalized. **What English skill do you need *the* most: speaking or writing?**

OR you could say something like this. **What English skill would be the most useful to you: writing or speaking?**

Comment: Wouldn't you rather ask "Which skill..."?

Comment: @Stephie Yes, you could say that.

Comment: Thank you so much @CanadianGirlScout. I appreciated your correction .^^